# Unlocking image in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, image-editing, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I can not edit size or position of image in Powerpoint slide which I received. It's box keys has "locked" view as shown in image below:
[image: Screen for PP problem]

It cannot moved or dragged or change properties, can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Locked shapes are a bit unusual; it's not something you can do in PPT itself, although shapes inserted by PPT's Design Ideas feature will be locked. To lock shapes yourself, you need to use an add-in like ShapeLocker or you need to manually edit the XML code inside the PPTX file.

If you want to have a go at editing the XML, start with John Korchok's starter tutorial here:
http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/02/xml-hacking-an-introduction/

John Wilson has a sample PPTX with text and image locked in various ways; studying the XML in this presentation should give you an idea how it's done:

http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/Downloads/LockDemo.pptx